# Amazon SQS java sdk stops after consuming 500 messages

Tags: java, spring-integration, messaging, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

I'm consuming messages from amazon SQS queue. I have thousands of messages in the queue. When I start the application (written in Java with spring framework) It starts polling messages from the queue and after receiving 500 messages It stops. If I start the application again It will consume another 500 messages.

My code is like...

**Connection factory**

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactoryActiveMQ() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-15");
    factory.setReceiveTimeout(3000L);
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = "sqsJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(CustomDestinationResolver resolver) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-15");
    factory.setReceiveTimeout(3000L);
    return factory;
}
```

**Listener**

```
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "sqsJmsListenerContainerFactory", destination = "sqs.queue")
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    //Processing message
}
```

Is anything I need to configure in amazon queue or in connection factory bean?
Thank you :-)

**Updated**: Added thread dump

**While Application is consuming messages**

DefaultMessageListenerContainer in thread dump is like

```
"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1@8242" prio=5 tid=0x18 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
      at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
      at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
      - locked <0x2230> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:918)
      at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
      - locked <0x2231> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:116)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
      at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
      at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
      at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2291)
      at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.deleteMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1340)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.deleteMessage(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:127)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.acknowledge.AutoAcknowledger.acknowledge(AutoAcknowledger.java:33)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.acknowledge.AutoAcknowledger.notifyMessageReceived(AutoAcknowledger.java:42)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.messageHandler(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:477)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.receive(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:410)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumer.receive(SQSMessageConsumer.java:157)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:413)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:293)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ConsumerPrefetchThread in thread dump is like

```
"ConsumerPrefetchThread-1@8723" daemon prio=5 tid=0x1b nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
      at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
      at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
      - locked <0x23a7> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:918)
      at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
      - locked <0x23a8> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:116)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
      at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
      at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
      at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2291)
      at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1021)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:319)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.getMessages(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:216)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.run(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:180)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**When Application stops consuming messages**

ConsumerPrefetchThread in thread dump is like

```
"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1@8242" prio=5 tid=0x18 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1151)
      at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:133)
      at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167)
      at com.ac.jms.senders.AbstractNoResponseSender.request(AbstractNoResponseSender.java:40)
      at com.ac.mic.listener.AbstractMicQueueListener.onMessage(AbstractMicQueueListener.java:117)
      at com.ac.mic.listener.MicQueueListener.onMessage(MicQueueListener.java:40)
      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source:-1)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
      at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185)
      at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:90)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:66)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:634)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:605)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
      at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ConsumerPrefetchThread in thread dump is like

```
"ConsumerPrefetchThread-1@8723" daemon prio=5 tid=0x1b nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.waitForPrefetch(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:273)
      at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.run(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:174)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try taking a thread dump when your consumer stops, to see what the container threads are doing. Maybe it's stuck in your code?

Comment: @GaryRussell I added thread dump. In this application, I'm using ActiveMQ also. I'm pushing messages that I will get from SQS to the ActiveMQ queues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like some kind of pool exhaustion in your code...

```
  at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1151)
  at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:133)
  at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167)
  at com.ac.jms.senders.AbstractNoResponseSender.request(AbstractNoResponseSender.java:40)
  at com.ac.mic.listener.AbstractMicQueueListener.onMessage(AbstractMicQueueListener.java:117)
  at com.ac.mic.listener.MicQueueListener.onMessage(MicQueueListener.java:40)
```

The container thread is stuck trying to get a session from `PooledConnection`.

Perhaps you are not returning sessions to the pool?

Consider using a `JmsTemplate` instead of your own code to talk to JMS. It avoids such issues.

Comment: I fixed this issue. I was not closing session & connection after sending the message. I learned how to use thread dump. Thanks @GaryRussell :)

Comment: @Piyush how to close them, please provide the example